# Problem to calculate the transformation matrix with superimposition_matrix of transformation.py

Tags: python, matrix, transformation

When trying to calculate a transformation matrix between two systems with the library transformations and the function superimposition_matrix, I get the following error :

> File "D:\Travail\Dev\projet Jarvis\collisions\Test dans
>   Jarvis\JarvisRobotics_20180717_1937\JarvisRobotics\outils_matrices.py",
>   line 839, in set_frame_passageV000
>       M = transformations.superimposition_matrix(list_base, list_ext, scale=True, usesvd=True) ValueError: eigenvector_of_symmetric_44()
>   failed

The data in entry are two list of ten vector(x,y,z):

```
<class 'list'>: [[2443.9128, -501.7427, -630.8925], [2126.8356, -703.2691, -678.1219], [1534.3236, -757.3283, -678.0219], [1532.8918, -339.4951, -682.6528], [2103.9974, -226.6539, -472.8035], [2297.246, 47.3245, -475.6743], [2429.3814, 88.5478, -476.0224], [2353.675, 614.8282, -447.7145], [1931.7996, 651.5278, -448.4745], [1604.6555, 664.6893, -448.8943]]

<class 'list'>: [[406.93, -373.8, 2559.99], [612.81, -65.74, 2566.76], [679.68, 520.63, 2542.36], [271.24, 532.19, 2612.08], [114.43, -31.73, 2439.24], [-157.93, -220.7, 2490.9], [-200.13, -350.38, 2501.29], [-722.9, -260.64, 2556.52], [-750.43, 160.15, 2551.35], [-759.14, 488.8, 2545.55]]
```

is anybody here to help me or to guide me to go further?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :) In order to get better answers and to avoid downvotes, please share your code and what you have tried so far. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry it's the first time i post ;). I do it now.

Answer (score 0):

def set_frame_passage_(list_pt_ref_base, list_pt_ref_ext):

```
str_erreur = ''

if len(list_pt_ref_base) == len(list_pt_ref_ext):
    nb_pts = len(list_pt_ref_base)

    array_base = np.zeros((nb_pts, 3))
    array_ext = np.zeros((nb_pts, 3))

    lg_array = 0
    for index in range(0, nb_pts):
        array_base[lg_array] = list_pt_ref_base[index][:3]
        array_ext[lg_array] = list_pt_ref_ext[index][:3]
        lg_array += 1

    M = superimposition_matrix(array_base, array_ext, scale=True)

    # valeurs de sortie
    xyzrpw = set_mat4x4_2_xyzrpw(M)
    mat_rdk = mat4x4_numpy_2_rdk(M)

    if not (not np.all(M) and xyzrpw and mat_rdk):
        return False

    return RetVal([True, dt.now, 'matrice de passage calculée avec succès !', M, xyzrpw, mat_rdk])

else:
    str_erreur = 'Les tailles du tableau du référentiel base('
    str_erreur += str(len(list_pt_ref_base))
    str_erreur += ') et du référentiel extérieur('
    str_erreur += str(len(list_pt_ref_ext))
    str_erreur += ') ne sont pas de la même taille !'
    print(str_erreur)
RetVal([False, dt.now, str_erreur])

list_ext_brute = [[406.93, -373.8, 2559.99, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0],
                    [612.81, -65.74, 2566.76, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0],
                    [679.68, 520.63, 2542.36, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0],
                    [271.24, 532.19, 2612.08, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0],
                    [114.43, -31.73, 2439.24, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0],
                    [-157.93, -220.7, 2490.9, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0],
                    [-200.13, -350.38, 2501.29, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0],
                    [-722.9, -260.64, 2556.52, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0],
                    [-750.43, 160.15, 2551.35, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0],
                    [-759.14, 488.8, 2545.55, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0],
                    [-358.39, 151.63, 2416.5, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0],
                    [-289.58, -60.31, 2410.38, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0],
                    [-86.04, 153.06, 2369.19, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0],
                    [-9.05, -92.79, 2361.71, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0]]

list_base_brute = [[2443.9128, -501.7427, -630.8925, -179.0604, 0.4017, 145.2487],
                    [2126.8356, -703.2691, -678.1219, -179.6825, 0.552, 124.2606],
                    [1534.3236, -757.3283, -678.0219, 179.9398, 0.6337, 88.9192],
                    [1532.8918, -339.4951, -682.6528, 179.7809, 0.5975, 74.2169],
                    [2103.9974, -226.6539, -472.8035, -179.4523, 0.3239, 153.7627],
                    [2297.246, 47.3245, -475.6743, -179.4523, 0.3237, 153.7627],
                    [2429.3814, 88.5478, -476.0224, -179.7454, -0.5832, -109.2463],
                    [2353.675, 614.8282, -447.7145, -179.7454, -0.5833, -109.2462],
                    [1931.7996, 651.5278, -448.4745, -179.7454, -0.5835, -109.2461],
                    [1604.6555, 664.6893, -448.8943, -179.7455, -0.5835, -109.2461],
                    [1925.4354, 246.4732, -379.1885, -179.7455, -0.5836, -109.2458],
                    [2137.8614, 172.319, -378.1896, -179.7455, -0.5836, -109.2459],
                    [1919.7934, -31.8006, -376.11, -179.7455, -0.5837, -109.2459],
                    [2164.5074, -117.227, -374.9585, -179.7455, -0.5837, -109.2459]]

mat_ = set_frame_passage_(list_base_brute, list_ext_brute)

if mat_.b_done:
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('xyzrpw = ' + str(mat_.res2))
    print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('vecteur translation : x=' + str(mat_.res2[0]) + ', y=' + str(mat_.res2[1]) + ', z=' + str(mat_.res2[2]))
    print('angles de rotation : r=' + str(mat_.res2[3]) + ', p=' + str(mat_.res2[4]) + ', w=' + str(mat_.res2[5]))
    print('----------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('Matrice de rotation numpy 4x4:')
    print(mat_.res1)
    print('----------------------------------------------------------------------------')
    print('Matrice de rotation roboDK 4x4:')
    print(mat_.res3)
else:
    print(mat_.str_msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

For information, I have found why I got this error:

The module transformation.py that i get is not complete and some functions are missing (in particular the one that raise an error) and due to the instruction "from transformation import *", there was apparently a default... I just use import the function that I need (superimposition_matrix) and I just test.

So now, the calculation passed but Now the result is not OK.

By an another software that we use for the robots ABB (Robotstudio), we have a function dedicated to the calculation of the Transformation Frames which is "DefAccFrame - Definition of an Accurate Frame between two systems". When we use it, we obtains the correct value (tested in real) and for now, this code does not work.

The issue is that this instruction is accessible only on ABB robots and I would to find a way to use it in any controller.

That's where I am today.
Really Thanks to everybody for all the help.